# HTTP request taking default method GET instead of POST

Tags: ios, swift, http, https, plivo

I'm trying to send sms through Plivo SMS API. Unfortunately, even though the request HTTP method is 'POST', the request posted as 'GET'. Please see my code below.

```
    let fromNumber = "11111111111"
    let toNumber = "111111234"
    let message = "Hello"

    do {
    let json = ["src":"\(fromNumber)","dst":"\(toNumber)","text":"\(message)"]
    let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(json, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)
        print(jsonData)

    // Build the request
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string:"https://"\(authId)":"\(authToken)"@api.plivo.com/v1/Account/"\(authId)"/Message")!)

  // I'm assigning the method should be 'POST' but why its going as 'GET'

    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"  
    request.HTTPBody = jsonData

    // Build the completion block and send the request
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request){ data, response, error in
            if error != nil{
                print("Error -> \(error)")
                return
            }

            do {
                let result = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject]

                print("Result -> \(result)")

            } catch {
                print("Error -> \(error)")
            }
        }

        task.resume()
        //return task



    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Please look at the screenshot, the request posted as 'GET' request.Please help me to resolve this isuue.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I kind of figured out what was the mistake. I should have put Message/ in the  url.

Before: NSURL(string:"https://"(authId)":"\                   (authToken)"@api.plivo.com/v1/Account/"(authId)"/Message")

Correct One: NSURL(string:"https://"(authId)":"\   (authToken)"@api.plivo.com/v1/Account/"(authId)"/**Message/**")

Without "/" in the end, request posted as "GET" instead of "POST"
Hope it helps others.

Answer (score 0):

I kinda figured it out, so the code looks like this:

```
        let json = ["src":"Source","dst":"Destination","text":"Test SMS"]
        let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(json, options: [])
        print(jsonData)

        // Build the request
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string:"https://authID:authToken@api.plivo.com/v1/Account/authID/Message/")!)

        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.HTTPBody = jsonData

        // Build the completion block and send the request
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request){ data, response, error in
            if error != nil{
                print("Error -> \(error)")
                return
            }

            do {
                let result = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: [])

                print("Result -> \(result)")

            } catch {
                print("Error -> \(error)")
            }
        }

        task.resume()
```